# Sed - delete all chars before dash

Tags: linux

I have below in file with contents

```
devtools-cloudformation
devtools-common-rpm
```

I want to remove devtools- and keep the rest of characters same, I tried below command but its removing all dashes

```
sed 's/.*-//' projects.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
sed 's/-/\n/;s/.*\n//' projects.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, you want to delete everything up till the **first** dash.
Try this:

```
sed 's/[^\-]*-//'
```

This deletes this first dash as well.

In case you want to maintain that first dash:

```
sed 's/[^\-]*-/-/'
```

The reason your solution doesn't work is the fact that the regular expression `.*-` means 'anything followed by a dash'.
The string `devtools-common-` matches this criterion and is therefore removed.
The expression I suggest says 'anything but a dash, followed by a dash'.